# Python: Creating a new dictionary while switching keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

If I am given a dictionary that has student names as keys and the subjects they're proficient in as a set of strings, how would I go about creating a new dictionary that would have the subjects as keys and everybody who's proficient in those subjects in a set?

Sorry, this is my first time asking a question here, so I'm not quite sure how to include snippets of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) making each of the subjects/values in each set a key and append/add each student to a list/set as values.

```
s = {'Sherman':{'calculus', 'english'},
 'Tyler': {'computers','history'},
'Kevin': {'chemistry','PE','geometry'},
'Joe': {'calculus','computers'},
'Bryan': {'nothing'},
'Steven': {'biology','research', 'algebra'}}

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in s.items(): # iterate over key/value tuples.
    for sub in v: # get each subject in the set/value
        d[sub].append(k) # add the students to a list and and make each subject a key
print(d)

 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'calculus': ['Sherman', 'Joe'], 'biology': ['Steven'], 'algebra': ['Steven'], 'geometry': ['Kevin'], 'computers': ['Tyler', 'Joe'], 'research': ['Steven'], 'english': ['Sherman'], 'nothing': ['Bryan'], 'chemistry': ['Kevin'], 'PE': ['Kevin'], 'history': ['Tyler']})
```

If you want sets as values use defaultdict(set) and .add instead of append:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for k,v in s.items():
    for sub in v:
        d[sub].add(k)
print(d)
 defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'calculus': set(['Sherman', 'Joe']), 'biology': set(['Steven']), 'algebra': set(['Steven']), 'geometry': set(['Kevin']), 'computers': set(['Tyler', 'Joe']), 'research': set(['Steven']), 'english': set(['Sherman']), 'nothing': set(['Bryan']), 'chemistry': set(['Kevin']), 'PE': set(['Kevin']), 'history': set(['Tyler'])})
```

Using a defaultdict means if the key does not exist in the dict it will be added and the value appended or just appended if it does  already exist, you can use dict.setdefault but a defaultdict is more efficient.

Comment: When I tried your way, I got traceback saying dictionaries don't have attributes 'iteritems'. Can you explain what you did here?

Comment: @Tyler, you are probably using python 3. Use .items() instead

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I should have mentioned that. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyler, please edit your Q to add the `python-3.x` tag.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried to fix `for k,v in s.iteritemsitems():` this part but something went wrong. Hope I didn't mess your answer